# Remove hyphen from Wordpress URL & replace with underscore

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url

I am having an issue with my WordPress Website URL for Individual Portfolio Page.

**Existing Pattern** : `www.abc.com/portfolio_page/logo-design/`

As hyphens are not a part of clean URL, I want to replace the hyphen with an underscore or keep only **portfolio**. I tried reading many articles but failed to implement. I tried with the below code but this doesn't work..

```
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=302]
```

**What i want** :

`www.abc.com/portfolio-page/logo-design/`

OR

```
 www.abc.com/portfolio/logo-design/
```

My htaccess file code as shown below

[image]

How Can I Do it..
Please Help..

Answer (score 0):

For just keeping just `/portfolio`, you can use this rule as your very first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(portfolio)[_-][^/]*/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [L,NC,NE,R=301]

# rest of your URLs go here
```

Comment: No This didn't work for me.. The URL pattern was changed, but the browser shows "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" this error..

Comment: Did you keep this as top rule an did you clear your browser cache? On my Apache this rule redirects `http://localhost/portfolio-page/logo-design/` to `http://localhost/portfolio/logo-design/`

Comment: I'm getting 50% of the pattern working.. Let me explain you.. After I used your code, when I open the portfolio page the URL is Updated to [link](www.abc.com/portfolio/) is displaying, but when i click on individual portfolio in this page it show "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" this error.. [link](www.abc.com/portfolio/logo-design)....

Comment: Also the Existing URL is www.abc.com/portfolio_page/logo-design/ not http://localhost/portfolio-page/logo-design/ as tested from your side.. I mean there is a underscore between "portfolio_page" in the URL

Comment: Even `http://localhost/portfolio_page/logo-design/` is redirected to `http://localhost/portfolio/logo-design/`. Can you edit question and provide your full .htaccess as I suspect some other rule misbehaving.

Comment: Your rule appears to be fine. Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Networking tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.